# Asymptotic proof examples

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I came across two asymptotic function proofs.

1. f(n) = O(g(n)) implies 2^f(n) = O(2^g(n))

   ```
   Given: f(n) ≤ C1 g(n)
        So, 2^f(n) ≤ 2^C1 g(n)                        --(i)

   Now, 2^f(n) = O(2^g(n)) → 2^f(n) ≤ C2 2^g(n)                  --(ii)

   From,(i) we find that (ii) will be true.
   Hence 2^f(n) = O(2^g(n)) is TRUE.
   ```

Can you tell me if this proof is right? Is there any other way to solve this?

2.f(n) = O((f(n))^2)

How to prove the second example? Here I consider two cases one is if f(n)<1 and other is f(n)>1.

```
Note: None of them are homework questions.
```

Comment: For example 2, what do you get with f(n) = 1/n ?

Comment: right. so you are saying that f(n) = O((f(n))^2) is TRUE only for f(n) >= 1.

Comment: What does “f(n) >= 1” mean?  Suppose f(n) = 1/n for odd n and 1+n for even n.

Comment: what i am saying is, in your example (1/n), for n=1, it proves the 
condition f(n)<= c.f(n)^2 ..for any constant c ......(f(n) >= 1)
but as n grows towards infinity, the f(n) grows towards zero (f(n) < 1)
and in that case, it does not prove the condition f(n)<=c.f(n)^2 (big oh definition).
So, the above property is true only when f(n)>=1

Comment: It's true whenever function f is bounded below by a positive number; see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempted-proof for example 1 looks well-intentioned but is flawed.  First,  “`2^f(n) ≤ 2^C1 g(n)`” means `2^f(n) ≤ (2^C1)*g(n)`, which in general is false.  It should have been written `2^f(n) ≤ 2^(C1*g(n))`.  In the line beginning with “Now”, you should explicitly say `C2 = 2^C1`.  The claim “(ii) will be true” is vacuous (there is no (ii)).

A function like `f(n) = 1/n` disproves the claim in example 2 because there are no constants N and C such that for all n > N, f(n) < C*(f(n))².  Proof: Let some N and C be given.  Choose n>N, n>C.  f(n) = 1/n = n*(1/n²) > C*(1/n²) = C*(f(n))².  Because N and C were arbitrarily chosen, this shows that there are no fixed values of N and C such that for all n > N, f(n) < C*(f(n))², QED.

Saying that “f(n) ≥ 1” is not enough to allow proving the second claim; but if you write “f(n) ≥ 1 for all n” or  “f() ≥ 1” it is provable.  For example, if f(n) = 1/n for odd n and 1+n for even n, we have f(n) > 1 for even n > 0, and less than 1 for odd n.  To prove that f(n) = O((f(n))²) is false, use the same proof as in the previous paragraph but with the additional provision that n is even.

Actually,  “f(n) ≥ 1 for all n” is stronger than necessary to ensure f(n) = O((f(n))²).  Let ε be any fixed positive value.  No matter how small ε is, “f(n) ≥ ε for all n > N'” ensures f(n) = O((f(n))²).  To prove this, take C = max(1, 1/ε) and N=N'.